# How to change iOS project include resource files through command line?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a CMS that generates apps, so the code is the same, but the resources changes per app (a xml file and some images).
Is there a way to include the xml file and images through command line? instead of doing it in xcode?

Regards,

Johnny

Comment: You should check the xcodebuild documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can interface with [xcode3build](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode3build.1.html) as [Till](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300549/how-to-change-ios-project-include-resource-files-through-command-line#comment5976973_5300549) said.

I am not sure how compatible it is with Xcode 4, and if that compatibility will be sufficient for your needs.